mySQL: How to query this properly?
I got this in my homework and can't figure it out, please help.
I have 3 tables:
owners(id, name), breeds(id, type), dogs(id, ownerid, breedid)
Connections:
owners.id = dogs.ownerid AND breed.id = dogs.breedid
My assignment is to find the the owners name whose name is LIKE the breed type.
Example: 'John Shepherd' has a 'german shepherd', so write his name, because of the match in the naming of the breed type and the owners name.
Tried to solve this like this:
SELECT owners.name
FROM owners, dogs, breed
WHERE owners.name LIKE CONCAT('%', breeds.type, '%')
AND dogs.breedid = breeds.id
AND dogs.ownerid = owners.id;

I know this is faulty because the owner is not called 'John German Shepherd'.
Is there a way to LIKE this query a way that the answer doesn't consider the whole breed.type or considers types with multiple words in it?

put another way - compare last token in name to any token in type?

I think it would be more accurate to compare any token in name to any token in type.
Maybe the owner called 'Jack XYZ' and his dog's type is 'Jack Russell Terrier'

Wouldn't that bring in John German Shepherd ?

Not sure what to do..
Is it possible to compare owners.name[0] with dogs.type[0], then owners.name[0] to dogs.type[1], owners.name[1] to dogs.type[0] finally owners.name[1] to dogs.type[1] and if there is any match write the the name? or something like this?
Sorry, I know this is not like programming, but i cant really put another way.. :/

The technique is called fuzzy matching. Unfortunately, mysql supports very basic pattern matching (like and regexp) and pronunciation (soundex) based fuzzy matching algorithms out of the box. I would probably do this in a language that comes with more advanced fuzzy matching functionalities / libraries, like python or R. This is not what sql was designed for.

Thank you P.Salmon and Shadow for your answers, i contacted with my teacher, and he replied my originally posted query, as the answer.
It looks like I overcomplicated this problem.. ://

@DávidMolnár: Please point you teacher to this article form October 2009: Bad Habits to Kick: Old-style JOINs

Try to use a wildcard in your SQL query to match parts of the owner's name with the breed type.
SELECT DISTINCT owners.name
FROM owners
JOIN dogs ON owners.id = dogs.ownerid
JOIN breeds ON dogs.breedid = breeds.id
WHERE LOWER(owners.name) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(breeds.type), '%');


My original answer was correct, I overcomplicated the assignment..:/
SELECT owners.name
FROM owners, dogs, breed
WHERE owners.name LIKE CONCAT('%', breeds.type, '%')
AND dogs.breedid = breeds.id
AND dogs.ownerid = owners.id;

Splitting multiple words of data wasn't needed, because the specific breeds.types can only be understood in regards multiple word phrases like 'German shepherd'.
The assignment stated I needed to find that owner's name who had the type of breed in the name. Doesn't states parts of the owner's dog's breedtype... What a draaaag. :D Thank you again @Shadow and @P.Salmon for your time and effort. Really appreciated !
